# Filter array using regex in React.js?

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I want to be able to check and see which keys start with the letters "gra" and only return that content. I've tried a few things with the code below. In one approach I added something like {key.match(/gra/g)} in the return html but it is not very efficient (and still outputs blank content). I've also tried adding something like this:

```
  if(String(this.props.profile[key]).match(/gra/g)))
```

also tried:

```
  if(this.props.profile[key].match(/gra/g))
```

but keep getting errors like ".match" is not a function or can't read undefined, etc. I've tried various other ways but can't seem to get it working right.

```
   var grapes = Object.keys(this.props.profile).map(function(key) {
        if(this.props.profile[key] !=null) {
                return (
                     <li key={key} className="example-class">
                         <label>{key}:</label>{ this.props.profile[key] }
                      </li>
                  );
              }
    }, this);


    <html>
       {grapes}
    </html>
```

So, all that to say, what is the best way to filter using regex for something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just filter the array

```
var grapes = Object.keys(this.props.profile)
                   .filter(function(key) {
                       return key && key.toLowerCase().indexOf('gra') === 0;
                   })
                   .map(function(key) {
                       return (
                         <li key={key} className="example-class">
                             <label>{key}:</label>{ this.props.profile[key] }
                         </li>
                       );
                   }, this);
```

Comment: hmm yeah hadn't thought of that. is "indexOf" similar to a .match()? just curious. thanks

Comment: `indexOf` is not similar to `match`, but it does look for strings in strings, so `str.indexOf('gra') === 0` is true if the string starts with `gra`

Comment: A regex is better if you need case-insensitive check.

Comment: yeah, I probably do need a case-insensitive check

Comment: If you need case-insensitive match, you do `key.toLowerCase().indexOf('gra')`

Comment: Note that `return key && key.indexOf...` removes any that are `undefined`, `null` or otherwise "falsy"

Comment: @adeno what if I only wanted to show a description for the first item in the array? How would that work? I've tired something like { this.props.length > 0 && this.props.length < 2 ? ("Description") : null}

Comment: If you just want the first one, you don't really have to map them, just shift of the first one, something like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/kvbfnrb7/

Comment: actually @adeneo I want to do both, so in the loop add a description for the first one, but then print out the rest without a description

Comment: Anything is possible, something like this then -> https://jsfiddle.net/kvbfnrb7/2/

Comment: hey @adeno one more question for you, how can I set html, along with the text, to the js variable? Or is that not possible, so something like:  var group_title = index === 0 ? '<h5>Food title</h5>' : ''; where the h5 is interpreted as a header